# Error when using self signed certificate in Mule on-prem

Tags: mule, mulesoft, on-premises-instances

For one of our application in Mule on-prem, we are using a self-signed certificate to achieve HTTPS and port 443. When we are hitting from postman or soapUI we are able to get the response back.

However, our client configured this API in one of their system and from that system when they trigger the url it is giving "**SSL handshake error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown**" error.

What could be causing this error which we don't see from the postman. Do the client has to add the certificate in their system or do we need to place the certificate in on-prem server? Any thoughts or suggestion on how we can resolve this and what is causing this error?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

The error clearly indicates that the client doesn't recognize the custom certificate. In Postman you probably accepted it as valid at some point. You need to configure the client to trust in the certificate. In Java based applications like Mule it is done with a trust store configurations.

Comment: Hi @aled, you saying that in the Mule Http listener I need to configure both keystore and truststore?

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. Based on the information you provided your client needs to trust your custom certificate.

Comment: By that I mean the client application that connects to your API.